# Testing Cordova application on physical iphone 6 without apple developer account/jailbroken phone

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

So I did a good amount of researching and most ways say you have to get a developer account or a jailbroken phone for this to work. Is there a way to get around either of these solutions to test my Cordova app on a physical device? I have the latest Xcode (Xcode 6.3.2) and I am trying to test on my iPhone 6 with OS 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the file

/your-project/platforms/ios/your-app-name.xcodeproject

The token `your-app-name` comes from the config.xml file,

```
<widget id="com.somedomain.someapp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>your-app-name</name>
    etc ...
```

Open that with Xcode, (make certain your device is plugged in) ... and run with your device as target. It will be compiled, linked, deployed and start on your device.

Avoid making any changes in the code with XCode. Instead do them in your ide and issue a 'cordova prepare' command in your project folder. Then press 'run' again in Xcode.

ps. i said `run` above, but `debug` works just fine.

Comment: Yeah I have done that. But it says it won't let me run on ios without a developer account. It tries to get me to add a developer account which I don't have.

Comment: Ah ... true and sorry. I have permanently one of X developper accounts configured in my Xcode. Not certain it can be done then.